# Why the App ICON and the name doesn't align center in Android?

Tags: android, xml, icons

Why the `App ICON` and the `name` doesn't align center to each other in `Android` ?

In `string.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">LTTT</string>
</resources>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml.xml`

```
<application
        android:name="aaa.bbb.ccc.lll"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
```

But the ICON and the name like the following picture:

[image]

It seems a space in front of the first letter.
Why the `App ICON` and the `name` doesn't align center to each other in `Android` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your app icon is not perfect it is taking transparent space from right. I have checked it and it is looking perfect.